# Apache ambari installation

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to install ambari server + agents.
I have a doubt regarding ambari.

I tried to install ambari.
It always gets link with hortonwork

My doubt is that I have hadoop cluster of my own in Ubunu 16.0.
Will ambari only work with HDP or is it possible to also make it work with custom built clusters?

Or if possible please share me detailed descriptive documentation

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear where you downloaded Ambari from, but it sounds like you used the Hortonworks version of it. Not directly from https://ambari.apache.org

[Ambari works with the concept of stacks](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Stacks+and+Services). Each stack has a set of services and components. HDP is such a stack, but [there are others](https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks), or you can even [define your own](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/How-To+Define+Stacks+and+Services), so yes, you can manage your own Hadoop installation components, but that really would be not much different from what Hortonworks already provides.

Besides, the HDP services and components have been tested to work together more throughly than off the shelf Hadoop installation.

If you don't want HDP components, there is also the [Apache Bigtop project](http://bigtop.apache.org/) that provides installation packs for many Hadoop related services

Ambari expects Java and Hadoop to be installed in a certain way. I'm not sure how easy it is to setup for an existing Hadoop install.

Comment: Thanks lot for clarifying it helps

Comment: Sure. If this as adequately answered your question, you can use the checkmark next to the post to accept it

Comment: Hi, followed step which you have shared above....still facing issue  Not able to get success in installing , i am using ubuntu 16 can you share me details about to fill what is Repositories under that OS, name, Base URL.    because of skipping that menu not able to install i believe ??

Comment: I got the url link from hortonwork tried to use it...but it say could not access base url trying to use HDP 2.6

Comment: The public Hortonworks repositories work fine... If it doesn't, it's a problem in your network / firewall. There is no other public URL that I know of. The Hortonworks documentation covers making a local mirror of their repositories, but you still need at least a one time external internet connection to get those, and that's what Ambari is letting you set, just an HTTP server holding installation packages for running `apt-get`